# Express command not working in terminal

Tags: node.js, macos, express, terminal

I am kind of new to node.js. I installed node fine and it works. I can run the node command in the terminal as well as the node package manager command(npm). Working on a Mac by the way. So I installed express globally with the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

After I was done installing it globally I installed it in a small folder where I am working on a project.

```
sudo install express
```

That gave me a node_modules folder inside of my site folder. After I was done that I went to install stylus using the express command and I got the error that express is not a command.

```
express -c stylus
```

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? I also tried to link the global express to the folder where I am working on the project using the following command:

```
sudo npm link express
```

The terminal said that this command ran, but I still cannot run the express command.

Comment: What version of Express do you have installed? If it's v4 rc or higher, I believe you need another module (http://expressjs.com/guide.html#executable)

Comment: Have you tried to reload the terminal window or at least use [`source`](http://ss64.com/osx/source.html) in it?

Comment: Running the express generator helped. I can now run the express command. I also ran express -c stylus and that seemed to work. If I run into anything else I will let you know, but I think I am good for now. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Express command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002448/express-command-not-found)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Thanks for asking questions on this one. I found that running express-generator instead of just express fixed the problem. The following code in the terminal worked.

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

Thanks again,

Comment: This worked for me!
I think you should accept your answer (although check the guidelines first). The official express guide mentions the generator: http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Comment: Worked for me too!

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If your express binary keeps doing nothing. Install node-legacy:

`sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Comment: Did you find this useful when you were having trouble installing express or was this a specific use case?

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. For some reasons, running 'sudo npm install -g express-generator' did not solve my problem.
The express command did nothing.

Comment: Were you running an older version of Node? What version of Node are you running. Did you change anything in your install of Node?

Comment: Express was doing nothing and it solved it. I have node.js v0.10.15 on ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Just a note, this does work but the question was specifically aimed at Mac's Terminal not Linux's Terminal.

Answer (score 5):

on ubuntu 14.04 nodejs 0.10 express did not work on terminal, though

`sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

made it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue. I tried all the solutions mentioned here. However couldn't get my problem solved.

This happens when location of express and nodejs is not same.

Issue arises when Node is installed using homebrew.

Just use this command export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH

NOTE: replace path with the path of express.

Follow [this](http://www.glatter-gotz.com/blog/2014/04/24/express-generator-on-osx-slash-homebrew-node-install/) link for help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `package.json` & `index.js` files. And instaled `express-generator` with `-g` tag.
If still getting error use like ex:`npx express --view=pug myapp --git`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my mac by forcing my user to own /usr/local/lib and running the command to install express-generator globally:

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib`

then:

`npm install -g express-generator`

After this you can go ahead and run your express commands:

`express -h`