# Express command not found

Tags: node.js, command-line, express

For some reason after installing Express globally on my machine with `npm install -g express` if I `cd` into a directory and try to run express I get the following error:

```
express: command not found.
```

Even if I run it with `sudo` I still get the same output. I've tried multiple different solutions to this problem and nothing has worked. I had installed node via `homebrew` which some threads on Stack Overflow indicated might have been a problem so I completely uninstalled node and reinstalled via the installer on nodejs.org (I'm now running v0.10.26) and the problem still persists.

If I go into my `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` Express is in there but within /usr/local/bin there is nothing regarding Express. I'm not sure if that's a problem or not but considering there are binaries for other globally installed node packages in that directory I'm thinking there may be something wrong there.

This is the exact output I get when I install:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/type-is/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge/1.0.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/merge-descriptors/0.0.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/path-to-regexp/0.1.2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/type-is/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/accepts/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static/1.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utils-merge/1.0.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/merge-descriptors/0.0.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/escape-html/1.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/path-to-regexp/0.1.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/parseurl/1.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/negotiator
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.2.0
express@4.0.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/express
├── methods@0.1.0
├── parseurl@1.0.1
├── utils-merge@1.0.0
├── merge-descriptors@0.0.2
├── escape-html@1.0.1
├── debug@0.8.0
├── cookie-signature@1.0.3
├── range-parser@1.0.0
├── fresh@0.2.2
├── qs@0.6.6
├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
├── cookie@0.1.0
├── path-to-regexp@0.1.2
├── type-is@1.0.0 (mime@1.2.11)
├── send@0.2.0 (mime@1.2.11)
├── serve-static@1.0.1 (send@0.1.4)
└── accepts@1.0.0 (negotiator@0.3.0, mime@1.2.11)
```

Answer (score 371, accepted):

With the release of Express 4.0.0 it looks like you need to do `sudo npm install -g express-generator`.

Comment: This worked thanks so much for your help! I was ready to pull my hair out over this last night.

Comment: sudo is not required for reasoned mentioned and will still work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938592/how-why-does-npm-recommend-not-running-as-root

Comment: Bummer, not even official documentation mentions it. ;-)

Comment: How did you find it, if this is not in the documentation how are we supposed to learn about it?

Comment: I thought i problem might be that express is not added to the 'Path'  (Environment variables)

Comment: FWIW official docs do mention it [now?] - http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html

Comment: The command sudo npm install -g express-generator worked for me

Answer (score 34):

You need to run:

```
npm install -gd express-generator
```

The original express with cli, now the cli split into separate express-generator package. Originally generated by the project is running express node app.js, because httpserver relevant code in app.js, and now this part of the code to the project directory `bin/www` below, app.js retain only achieve app logic code, you need to run the `bin/www`. Just a very simple application and refinement package dependency version changes.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this challenge for a number of days. After deep search, I learned that one has to read every available resource especially from the parent source [in this case EXPRESSJS.COM]. Here is a quick fix.

Beginning with version 4.0+ you don't necessarily need to install express-generator if you are running Node 8.2+. Simply run

```
npx express-generator
```

The express-generator will run just the way it runs when you run:`express`

For more details see [Getting Started](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)

Happy reading and research hours.

Answer (score 3):

I have been recently trying to install express-generator , however it would give out ,

```
$ zsh : command not found : express
```

It was after i did

```
$ sudo npm install -g express
$ sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

But then , i saw  the console log of the npm install commnand

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.1.0/bin/express -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.1.0/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js
```

which gave a hint that the executable express is in the bin folder.

So the solution is :
Open up ~/.zshrc or ~/.bashrc
and export the path as follows:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.1.0/bin:$PATH
```

It works now.