# 'express' command not found on mac

Tags: node.js, macos, express, npm, fish

Definitely a noob question so please don't judge but this has been bothering me for a while.

No more how many times I run `$ sudo npm install -g express-generator` or `$ npm install express -g`, everything seems to install but the command `$ express` still doesn't exist.

I'm running fish shell. Also, I'm assuming this is an issue coming from my PATH file, but I'm lost on if that's .bash_profile or .bashrc.

My .bash_profile has the three lines in it:

```
  export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=/Users/username/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express:$PATH
  export PATH=/Users/username/.node/bin/express:$PATH
```

and my .bashrc file has nothing regarding node in it.

When express installs, it returns:

```
  /Users/username/.node/bin/express -> /Users/username/.node/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express
  /Users/username/.node/lib
```

but when I command `which node` it returns

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

When I try to run `$ls -l /usr/local/bin/express` it returns:

```
ls: /usr/local/bin/express: No such file or directory
```

Cannot find the diagnosis of why the express command won't work after installation.

Comment: Q: `node` and `npm` both work from the command line, correct?  Q: Could you please update your post with the output for this command: `ls -l /usr/local/bin/express`?  Q: Is there an error message?  If so, please copy/paste the exact text into your post.

Comment: updated with what is returned that command

Comment: OK: 1) Q: What happens with `express-generator`, and `which express-generator`?  2) Please look at this thread: [Express command not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002448/express-command-not-found)

Comment: @paulsm4 I tried everything in that link and have not found a solution yet. Running `$ which express-generator` yields `which: no express-generator in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/go/bin)`

Comment: Please clarify which shell you are using. What does `echo $SHELL` output? I'm confused because you talk about .bashrc and .bash_profile which are not relevant if you're using fish.

Comment: It's written in the post I'm using fish shell :)

Comment: @paulsm4 `ls: /usr/local/bin/express: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

If you are running fish, your .bash_profile is ignored, of course!

The preferred way to add /Users/username/.node/bin/ to your $PATH in fish is like so:

```
set -U fish_user_paths $fish_user_paths /Users/username/.node/bin/
```

that's just something you run once, at the command line - not something you put in a startup file.

If you prefer to use startup files, you can instead modify your `~/.config/fish/config.fish` like so:

```
set PATH $PATH /Users/username/.node/bin/
```

Comment: I did both of these, and they won't work. However, when I `echo $PATH`, I get: 

   `/usr/local/bin /Users/username/.node/bin/`
   `/usr/sbin`
    `/usr/local/bin` 
    `/usr/bin `
    `/bin`
    `/usr/sbin` 
    `/sbin` 
    `/opt/X11/bin`
    `/usr/local/go/bin`
    `/Users/[myusername]/.node/bin`


Isn't this too many? Also how do I remove the `/Users/username/.node/bin/` from my $PATH?

Comment: It is very surprising that `/Users/username/.node/bin/` would be in $PATH but `express` would not be found. Does the file `/Users/username/.node/bin/express` actually exist? To be sure, username was meant to be replaced with your actual username of course.

Comment: If you added that path element via fish_user_paths, you could just write `set -e fish_user_paths[1]` to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

From the symlink after the install, the `express` binary should be available in the `/Users/username/.node/bin` directory. The reason you can't use the binary is because the `/Users/username/.node/bin` directory is not in your `$PATH`. Whats in the `$PATH` is the binary itself.

When you add a directory to your `$PATH`, you can execute binaries from within the directory. Currently, your `$PATH` points to the `/Users/username/.node/bin/express` which does not have any binaries within it. You should correct it to:

```
export PATH=/Users/username/.node/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: followed this advice and it still won't quite work. tried commanding `$ echo $PATH ` and it returns:

   `/usr/local/bin /Users/username/.node/bin/`
   `/usr/sbin`
    `/usr/local/bin` 
    `/usr/bin `
    `/bin`
    `/usr/sbin` 
    `/sbin` 
    `/opt/X11/bin`
    `/usr/local/go/bin`
    `/Users/[myusername]/.node/bin`

Isn't this too many? Would you know how I can remove the `/Users/username/.node/bin/` from my $PATH?