# express: command not found error

Tags: node.js, express, terminal, installation

I know there are many answers in this topic but still not solved my problem.

My settings:

- Mac OS
- Node.js v8.11.2
- npm v5.6.0

I tried this:

- `sudo npm install -g express-generator` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002448/express-command-not-found)
- `reinstall node.js` from [here](http://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/)
- express install after `npm init`. (But just 'package.json' is made when I finish [this tutorial](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html))

When I install express and express-generator,

```
$ npm install -g express
+ express@4.16.3
updated 1 package in 1.499s

$ npm install -g express-generator
/Users/soodiamond/.npm-global/bin/express -> 
/Users/soodiamond/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/express-generator/bin/express-cli.js
+ express-generator@4.16.0
updated 1 package in 0.925s
```

still not find express command

```
$ express myapp
-bash: express: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Module `express` don't have `bin` in package.json, so you can't call it.
(`npm` don't create file `express` in bin folder)

When you run : `sudo npm install -g express-generator`,

Comment: Thanks @kỉaT  I tried to call `express-generator` but error is same. `-bash: express-generator: commant not found`

Comment: Sorry you, when install `express-generator` you can call `express`.
You should check bin folder (I don't use Mac OS, so i don't know path of bin folder).

Comment: Yes that's my path problem. I found express folder path is not registered in $PATH. When I added it then works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem while installing express for the first time. Probably the @4.16 version has some issues. 

Try:
`sudo npm install -g express@4.13.1`

Worked for me!